How to uploading images with Dropzone on the nodejs nuxt 3
I am making a project in frontend (nuxt 3) and backend (nodejs), my codes are as follows.
I can't understand why no uplaoding image path on database.
This is backend side
This is upload utils file
utils/fileUpload.js
import multer from "multer";
import path from "path";

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, 'uploads');
   },
   filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
   }
});

const upload = multer({
   storage,
   fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
         cb(null, true);     
      }else {
         cb(new Error('MimeType not supported'), false);
      }
   },
});

export default upload;

This is route which I post request upload file
bookRoute.js
router.post('/upload', authMiddleware.authenticateUser, upload.single('image'), bookController.uploadFile);

This is controller
bookController.js
This is controller which I post request fron dropzone file upload.
const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      if (!req.file) {
         return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
      }

      const filePath = req.file.path;
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully', filePath });
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server ERROR' });
   }
};

const store = async (req, res) => {
   try {

      upload.single('image')(req, res, async (err) => {
         if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
         }

         const { name, author, description, page } = req.body;
         const uploader = req.user._id;
         const image = req.file ? req.file.path : null;

         console.log('Uploaded file:', req.file);
         console.log('Image path:', image || 'No file');

         if (!image) { // Check if image was uploaded
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Image upload failed.' });
         }


         const existingBook = await Book.findOne({ name, author });

         if (existingBook) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'A book with same name and author already exist!' });
         };

         const newBook = await Book.create({
            name,
            author,
            description,
            page,
            uploader,
            image
         });

         return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Book created successfully',
            books: newBook
         });

      });

   } catch (error) {
      // Handle validation errors
      if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
         if (checkValidationErrors(error, res)) return;
      } else {
         console.error("Error at creating book", error);
         return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: 'Internal Server ERROR' });
      }
   }
};

This is frontend side
DashboardBooks.vue
onMounted(() => {
  if (dropzoneElement.value) {
    dropzone = new Dropzone(dropzoneElement.value, {
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/books/upload",
      thumbnailWidth: 150,
      maxFilesize: 2, // Max file size in MB
      dictDefaultMessage: "Drag files here or click to upload",
      paramName: "image",
      acceptedFiles: "image/*",
      init: function () {
        this.on("sending", (file, xhr, formData) => {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${authStore.token}`);
        });

        this.on("success", (file, response) => {
          // Handle success
         console.log("File uploaded successfully", response);
        });

        this.on("error", (file, message) => {
          // Handle error
          console.error("Upload failed:", message);
        });
      },
    });
  }
});

The photo does not load in the console
File uploaded successfully {message: 'File uploaded successfully', filePath: 'uploads/1725613201618.jpg'}
console.log('Uploaded file:', req.file);
console.log('Image path:', image || 'No file');

Server listening on 5000
Uploaded file: undefined
Image path: No file

console.log('Uploaded file:', req.file);
console.log('Image path:', image || 'No file');

Server listening on 5000
Uploaded file: undefined
Image path: No file

